# How to do OOP and MVC properly

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

This afternoon I wrote this but it feels dirty to me. Since I'm learning OOP and MVC, I would like to know if there is a proper way to change nested object's attributes.

For example what is the cleanest way to modify an attribute from an object contained in an object, etc ?

The whole code is here https://github.com/Meezouney/Chess_tournament

If you have any advise, I'll take it :)

Thanks

```py
def enter_match_results(self, nth_round, nth_match):
        n_round = self.tournament.get_list_of_rounds()[nth_round]
        game = n_round.get_list_of_match()[nth_match]
        players = game.get_players()

        for i, player in enumerate(players):
            if i == 0:
                valid_input = 0
                while not valid_input:
                    score = self.view.ask_results(player)
                    if score == "0" or score == "0,5" or score == "0.5" or score == "1":
                        if ',' in score:
                            score = score.replace(',', '.')
                        valid_input = 1
                        self.tournament.get_list_of_rounds()[nth_round].get_list_of_match()[nth_match].set_score_player_1(float(score))
                        
                    else:
                        self.view.display_score_error()
            elif i == 1:
                valid_input = 0
                while not valid_input:
                    score = self.view.ask_results(player)
                    if score == "0" or score == "0,5" or score == "0.5" or score == "1":
                        if ',' in score:
                            score = score.replace(',', '.')
                        valid_input = 1
                        self.tournament.get_list_of_rounds()[nth_round].get_list_of_match()[nth_match].set_score_player_2(float(score))
                        
                    else:
                        self.view.display_score_error()
```

I am trying to figure out the philosophy of OOP by practicing.

Comment: The cleanest way to modify an "attribute" in any object is to write a method that does it for you.  That way you preserve encapsulation.  However, methods should generally perform meaningful actions, not just tweak a member of an object.  What is the meaningful action you want to take here?

Comment: A "meaningful action" would be something along the lines of "As a [user] I want to [perform some action] so that I can [accomplish some result]."

Comment: Basically, the user, which is a chess referee is using "input" to give me a score of a chess game (0, 0.5 or 1) and I'd like to update the score of the player contained within the "Match", contained within the "Round", contained within the "Tournament"

Comment: Write an `UpdateScore()` method.